# Import .txt file to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to import the text file to SQL Server 2008.
Obviously, the text file is like,

```
AA89ATOZ                MR        1  PMANUAL   >0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1.
```

The record has thousand records like this.
When I load the text file using excel, it will be set all texts in one row.
I have read some related answer, which is

```
AA89ATOZ,MR,1,PMANUAL,>0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.
```

If I can do make like above, how can I change it?
Does it have any function to split text on row?
Please let me know the answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options for inserting data into SQL Server from a text file. Here are a couple that are widely used.

The SQL Server Import and Export wizard is pretty straightforward, and the resulting Integration Services package can be saved and scheduled for execution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx

Or you can use the T-SQL BULK INSERT command. This requires that the text file is either on the database server filesystem or available via UNC path:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx