# insert tab separated records to sql server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, bulkinsert

Is there any tool which can read a text file and insert the records that separated by tab characters in the file to a sql server table.
i can do that by developing a small c# application but i wonder if there is already a tool doing that.

Comment: Have a look at this SO post: [Import .txt file to SQL Server 2008][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791710/import-txt-file-to-sql-server-2008

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bulk insert:

Have a look at this SO post: [Import .txt file to SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791710/import-txt-file-to-sql-server-2008)

and

[SQL SERVER – Import CSV File Into SQL Server Using Bulk Insert – Load Comma Delimited File Into SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server bulk insert? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx