# Importing 2 .txt files to sql server database using asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, import, streamreader

I have 2 .txt files with data that i need to import to a sql server database in order to continue my project in Visual Studio C#.  I was told to use the Stream writer/reader.  Can someone explain to me how to use it, and show me all the aspects of how to do it? I am very new.

Comment: There are probably a million examples of this if you google it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to insert the information by hand, you can follow the tips provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791710/import-txt-file-to-sql-server-2008).

If you want to do it through C#, here are some links to get you started:

- First you need to parse the text files to retrieve the data.  Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858756/how-to-parse-a-text-file-with-c-sharp) on how to do that.
- Next you'll need to insert the information.  Here's a [Beginners guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) to doing that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have an example here.

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/bulk-insert-example-using-an-idatareader-to-strong-dataset-to-sql-server-xml/

It was written for VS2003, but updating it to VS2010 or (or 2008 or other) would be trivial.

It does not use a stream reader.  It uses OleDb.
The above is a good solution if you need to do any validations on the data before inserting it.

Here is another idea.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom